# Standard Error Loss vs. Absolute Loss

Tags: probability

I understand that

Squared error$(Y,X) = (Y - X)(Y - X)$ and

Absolute error$(Y,X) = |Y - X|$

If I've predicted the value $X = 0$.

Based on this, I draw the squared error loss as $Y$ varies from $-2$ to $2$ on a piece of paper. Now draw the absolute error loss as $Y$ varies from $-2$ to $2$.

My question is:

1. Which penalty is heavier when $Y$ is close to my predicted value of $X$? Standard Error or Absolute Error?
2. What about when $Y$ is far from my predicted value?

It seems like they are both equal when the $Y$ value is closer to $X$ but the farther it goes out, the penalty seems to be harsher with squared error.

Answer (score 1):

When plotting the two, you hopefully had this plot down:

[image: Plot of |x| and x^2 from -2 to 2]

The purple plot is squared error and the blue plot is absolute error. From these plots, you see that squared error is smaller than absolute error when we're close to 0 (i.e. your prediction is close to your actual value) and squared error is much larger than absolute error when you're far away from 0. They agree when the error is equal to 1.

Even though the plots meet up at 0 when x = 0 you shouldn't think of the two types of errors as being the same when we're that close.